# how to display the webpage using phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, phonegap

I'm developing one application for iphone using phone gap.I that I need to display the web page when we click on one button. I designed that button using html. How to display the webpage?

Comment: why not use the onclick=function_name() part while creating button and implement the function in javascript?

Comment: Iam new for this platform.so how to access  webpage in java script.

Comment: r u even using jquery mobile, or what r u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach a click handler to that button and use this http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: I need to write function on javascript

Comment: var obj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl("http://www.google.com"); i written this one on javascript function.But it was not working

Comment: i think we r not getting what u really want to open.
if u want to open an external url in safari, u should use a href

Comment: I want to open webpage when iam click on button.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a phonegap plugin in called childBrowser which will help you to show an external webpage without leaving your app check it at [ChildBrowser for android](http://s.zah.me/Hq6vzF) and this is [ChildBrowser for ios](http://s.zah.me/Hq6Kuu)